# Capturar errores react native hook

Tags: react-native, expo

Tengo una aplicación implementada con react native (expo), en la cual envió todos los errores a la plataforma rollbar. Es parte de un conjunto de aplicaciones todas enlazadas entre ellas.
Por esta razón en ocasiones se encuentran errores que no son controlados, como Ejemplo una dirección de correo vacío, que es un campo obligatorio pero la aplicación que lo genero no cuenta con ese campo por mencionar alguno.
La pregunta es:

Existe la forma o mecanismo para obtener todos los errores controlados o no en un mismo lugar y proceder no se a mostrar una pantalla con un mensaje de error.
Es decir:
En mi App.js tener el método de capturar esos errores sin utilizar u useContext ni useMemo, ya que puede ser un error a la hora de renderizar la vista.
Estoy abierto a debate

```
/**En express js utilizo */
app.use((err, reg, res, next)=>{
  console.log("****")
  rollbar.error("Error General:",err.stack)
  next()
})
```